# Category page shows Oops! That page can’t be found

Tags: categories

The article categories can't show the articles.

It appears the error message "Oops! That page can’t be found."

How do I fix it?

[image]

Comment: I don't think it is code problem. The site is just created and using it's own basic theme.

Comment: Have you verified your permalinks (reflush them). Do you have any custom rewrite rules. Is you `.htaccess` file correct.

Comment: @PieterGoosen How do　Ｉ　ｃｈｅｃｋ　ｗｉｔｈ　ｉｔ？